# How to use HttpsURLConnection through proxy by setProperty?

Tags: java, networking, proxy, outputstream, httpsurlconnection

Network environment:

> Https Client<=============>Proxy Server<==============>Https Server
>                                                     192.168.17.11<-----extranet------>192.168.17.22
>   10.100.21.10<----intranet----->10.100.21.11
>
> ps: Http Client without default gateway, but it can ping to 10.100.21.11

Description:

> OS: Ubuntu 12.04 on 3 hosts
>   Https Client: Implement with java(openjdk-6).Have one network-interface.
>   Proxy Server: Apache2.2.Have two network-interfaces.
>   Https Server: Tomcat6.Have one network-interface.

I use two method to implement *httpsurlconnection* through proxy:
(For facilitate I do not write down about ssl handle function for checking *serverTrusted* and *hostnameVerifier* issue.If need I will update.)

## 1.Proxy class

```java
InetSocketAddress proxyInet = new InetSocketAddress("10.100.21.11",80);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxyInet);
URL httpsUrl = new URL("https://192.168.17.22:8443/test");
HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) httpsUrl.openConnection(proxy);

httpsCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpsCon.setDoInput(true);
httpsCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStream out = httpsCon.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter owriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

owriter.write("<request>test</request>");
owriter.flush();
owriter.close();
...
```

This method workable and I observed packets flow also met my expectation.
*HttpClient ---> ProxyServer ---> HttpServer*

But when I use set Property method:

## 2.setProperty

```java
System.setProperty("http.proxySet", "true");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost",10.100.21.11);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","80");

URL httpsUrl = new URL("https://192.168.17.22:8443/test");
HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection)httpsUrl.openConnection();

httpsCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpsCon.setDoInput(true);
httpsCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStream out = httpsCon.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter owriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

owriter.write("<request>test</request>");
owriter.flush();
owriter.close();
...
```

I got a `NoRouteToHostException: Network is unreachable`.
It make me confused.I did not see any packets between HttpClient and ProxyServer.
But HttpClient can ping to ProxyServer(10.100.12.10 ping 10.100.21.11)

So I remove proxy setting(as without using proxy):
Also got `NoRouteToHostException: Network is unreachable`.
I thought this is reasonable.Because there is no route to extranet.

I guess it seems like to *setProperty* method that the inner function of *httpsUrlConnection* will to check this url can be reachable or not.

But it is weird. 1st method can be success.

Have any idea? Or what are different between 1st and 2nd method?

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

## Update

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost",10.100.21.11);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","80");
```

It can work and packets flow are correct what I expect for.
 
But set https.proxyPort=443 is not workable for me

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","443");
```

It will thorow a exception as bellow:

```
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server 
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:770)
....
```

So I thought Apache Proxy have also to be modified to the right configuration.

Comment: There is no such property as http.proxySet.

Comment: yes. this property really do not need to be set.Thank you~

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your URL connection is https whereas you are only setting the http proxy.

Try setting the https proxy.

```
//System.setProperty("https.proxySet", "true"); 
 System.setProperty("https.proxyHost",10.100.21.11);
 System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","443");
```

**EDIT** 
@EJP is correct. There is no https.proxySet .. I copied your original question and included in the answer.

Comment: There is no such property as https.proxySet.

Comment: I think this is the right answer while sending a request "https" url. 
the key of setProperty is https.proxyHost/proxyPort instead of http.proxyHost/porxyPort.

Comment: For all which comes here: It's very important to set the port as a STRING, otherwise it will not be used

Answer (score 12):

You will need to create a `Proxy` object for it. Create one as below:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyServer, Integer.parseInt(proxyPort)));
```

Now use this proxy to create the `HttpURLConnection` object.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);
```

If you have to set the credentials for the proxy, set the `Proxy-Authorization` request property:

```
String uname_pwd = proxyUsername + ":" + proxyPassword
String authString = "Basic " + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(uname_pwd.getBytes())
connection.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", authString);
```

And finally, you connect:

```
connection.connect();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
First, I use 1st method is creating a proxy object and it is workable for me. 
Second, the url what I need is "https" so I think to use HttpsURLConnection is correct.

Answer (score 1):

thank you @divinedragon!

Same code on kotlin:

```
 fun testProxy(login: String, pass: String, proxyData: ProxyData): String {
    val url = URL("http://api.ipify.org")
    val proxy = Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress(proxyData.ip, proxyData.port))
    val connection = url.openConnection(proxy) as HttpURLConnection

    val loginPass = "$login:$pass"
    val encodedLoginPass = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(loginPass.toByteArray())
    val authString = "Basic $encodedLoginPass"
    connection.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", authString);
    with(connection) {
        requestMethod = "GET"  // optional default is GET
        connectTimeout = 2000
        readTimeout = 2000
        return inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
    }
}
```