# not able to call url from java code

Tags: java, http

I am trying to call URL from java but am getting error as java.net.UnknownHostException:

**Java Code:**

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.gettingagile.com/feed/rss2/");
    HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    String code = String.valueOf(request.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println("Error code "+code);
```

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: am getting java.net.UnknownHostException: www.gettingagile.com

Comment: Maybe you're behind a firewall that is blocking access, or maybe your dev machine isn't even properly connected to the internet. your code seems fine

Comment: It also works for me. Look if you have another application that it's blocking your network connection.

Comment: May be your machine has proxy configurations, but your code doesn't identify any gateways...
try using this method: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432961/how-do-i-make-httpurlconnection-use-a-proxy
or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927079/how-to-use-httpsurlconnection-through-proxy-by-setproperty

Answer (score 1):

An UnknownHostException generally means that java couldn't resolve the host, in this case `www.gettingagile.com`.

Maybe your firewall is blocking access for java, maybe your computer is not connected to the internet or there might be a problem with your DNS server.

Can you surf to `www.gettingagile.com` in your browser? And can you ping the address from a shell or commandline?